# BackgroundGeolocation does not exist in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic4

Steps to reproduce
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation@alpha
npm install @ionic-native/background-geolocation
ionic cordova run android

Please see the following adb log

```
03-08 13:54:54.102 18251 18251 D SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost/polyfills.js: Line 2557 : Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation.BackgroundGeolocation does not exist.   
03-08 13:54:54.102 18251 18251 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2557)] "Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation.BackgroundGeolocation does not exist.", source: http://localhost/polyfills.js (2557)   
03-08 13:54:56.622 18251 18251 D SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost/vendor.js: Line 50653 : Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.   
03-08 13:54:56.622 18251 18251 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(50653)] "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.", source: http://localhost/vendor.js (50653)   
03-08 13:54:58.942 18251 18251 D SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost/cordova.js: Line 1219 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.   
03-08 13:54:58.942 18251 18251 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1219)] "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: http://localhost/cordova.js (1219)
```

Comment: Can u share the platform versions:  `ionic cordova platform` i.e., `cordova platform ls` output?